# Keras fit generator - ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, error-handling, generator

i'm trying to fit my deep learning model with a custom generator.

When i fit the model, it shows me this error:
[image]

I tried to find similar questions, but all the answers were about converting lists to numpy array. I think that's not the question in this error. My lists are all in numpy array format. This custom generator is based on a custom generator from  [here](https://medium.com/@mrgarg.rajat/training-on-large-datasets-that-dont-fit-in-memory-in-keras-60a974785d71)

This is the part of code where I fit the model:

```
        train_generator = RepresentationGenerator(representation_path=representations_path, target_path=target_path,
                                              filenames=training_filenames, batch_size=batch_size)
    val_generator = RepresentationGenerator(representation_path=representations_path, target_path=target_path,
                                            filenames=validation_filenames, batch_size=batch_size)
    self.model_semantic.fit_generator(train_generator,
                            epochs=10,
                            verbose=1,
                            validation_data=val_generator,
                            )
    return 0
```

where the variables are:

- **representations_path** - is a string with the directory to the path where i store the training files, that which file is the input to model
- **target_path** - is a string with the directory to the path where i store the target files, that which file is the target of the model (output)
- **training_filenames** - is a list with the names of training and target files (both have the same name, but they are in different folders)
- **batch_size** - integer with the size of the batch. It has the value 7.

My generator class is below:

```
import np
from tensorflow_core.python.keras.utils.data_utils import Sequence
```

```
class RepresentationGenerator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, representation_path, target_path, filenames, batch_size):
        self.filenames = np.array(filenames)
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.representation_path = representation_path
        self.target_path = target_path

    def __len__(self):
        return (np.ceil(len(self.filenames) / float(self.batch_size))).astype(np.int)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        files_to_batch = self.filenames[idx * self.batch_size: (idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_x, batch_y = [], []
        for file in files_to_batch:
            batch_x.append(np.load(self.representation_path + file + ".npy", allow_pickle=True))
            batch_y.append(np.load(self.target_path + file + ".npy", allow_pickle=True))

        return np.array(batch_x), np.array(batch_y)
```

These are the values, when the method fit is called:
[image]

**How can I fix this error?**

Thank you mates!

---

When I call the method fit_generator, it calls the method fit.
[image]

The method fit, calls the method func.fit and it passes the variable Y that is set as None

[image: g]

The error occurs in this line:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final solution:

Import from the correct place:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
```

---

**Old answers:**

If `__getitem__` is never called, the problem might be in `__len__`. You're not returning an `int`, you're returning a `np.int`.

I suggest you try:

```
def __len__(self):
    length = len(self.filenames) // self.batch_size
    if len(self.filenames) % self.batch_size > 0:
        length += 1

    return length
```

But if `__getitem__` is being called and your data returned, then you should inspect your arrays.

Get an item from the generator yourself and check the content:

```
x, y = train_generator[0]
```

- Are they single arrays? Or are they arrays of arrays? (Must be single)
- What are their shapes? Do they have the expected shapes?
- What are their types? Usually they should be `float`, sometimes `int` (for inputs to embedding layers), very rarely `string` (for inputs to custom layers that know how to treat strings).

  - The outputs must always be `float`, at most `int` (for sparse losses)

---

Other suppositions, you're using `fit` with `batch_size` while using a generator.... this is strange and the "if" clauses inside the method may not be well prepared, you might be falling into another training case.

Go straight to the usual options:

```
self.model_semantic.fit_generator(train_generator, 
                                 epochs=10,
                                 verbose=1,
                                 validation_data=val_generator)
```

Your generator is a `Sequence`, it already has a `__len__`, you don't need to specify `steps_per_epoch` or `validation_steps`.
Every generator has automatic batch sizes, every step is a batch and that's it. You don't need to specify `batch_size` in `fit_generator`.

If you're going to use `fit`, go like this:

```
...fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch = len(train_generator), 
       epochs = 10, verbose = 1,
       validation_data = val_generator, validation_steps = len(val_generator))
```

---

Finally, you should be hunting for anything that might be `None` (as the error message suggests) in your code.

- Check if every function has a `return` line.
- Check all inputs of your generator in `__init__`.
- Print the filenames inside the generator.
- Get the `__len__` of the generator.
- Try to get an item from the generator: `x, y= train_generator[0]`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I made the changes that you said and the error is still the same. The methods __len__ and the methods __get_item__ are never been called. The error is throwed because it expected an Y variable, and my y variable is set as None.

Comment: @JoãoCastilho, Go to the second section of the answer (refresh the page and see the new complete answer)

Comment: I see, maybe try fit like in the updated answer? (No batch size)

Comment: Now, the method __len__ is called and returns a integer of 74. But the error still occurs in the same line. Y is None

Comment: When i call the line "x, y = train_generator[0]" it returns me an array of shape(7,335,255,54) for x and (7,335,255,15) for y like it's supposed to be

Comment: Then it's something I can't imagine :( --- Are you mixing `tensorflow.keras` with standard `keras`? --- Can you try to use `from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence`?

Comment: It was that. Thanks a lot mate. i was importing from tensorflow_core.python.keras.utils.data_utils instead of tensorflow.keras.utils. Thank you a lot, you're the BOSS